# How to replace the contents of a target in Svelte instead of appending to children?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Calling new Component({ target }) appends component to target, I want to replace all the old content of the target with the new component. How can I do that?

Comment: Are your talking about routing ? if yes, try this : https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're hydrating server-rendered markup, it's better to use the `hydrate: true` option ([docs here](https://svelte.dev/docs#Creating_a_component)).

If `target` was previously occupied by a Svelte component, it's better to call that component's `$destroy()` method.

Otherwise, the simplest way is to just empty out the `target` element:

```js
target.innerHTML = '';
new Component({ target });
```

Comment: Can't edit but the link is outdated, I think the new relevant link is : https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api#creating-a-component

Answer (score 4):

```js
function replaceTarget (target) {
    const component = new MySvelteComponent({
        target: target.parentElement,
        anchor: target,
    });
    target.remove();
}
```

This prepends the new component just before the target element (in the target's parent), and then removes the target.

Relevant documentation on `anchor`:
https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api#creating-a-component

Probably not a good idea to use with `target === <body>`.

Comment: How to keep attributes of the previous target? (For instance `name`, `id`, `class` etc.)

Comment: @cassepipe yes. I added an answer below.

Comment: @Lindsay-Needs-Sleep
Can't edit but I think the new correct link is : https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api#creating-a-component

Answer (score 3):

I use this method to replace a DOM element with a svelte component while keeping most of the properties (id, name etc.)

```js
export function replaceTargetByComponent(target, Component, options) {
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment()
    var props = {
        id: target.id,
        name: target.name,
        value: target.value,
        checked: target.checked,
        readonly: target.readOnly,
        ...target.dataset,
        ...options,
    }
    const component = new Component({
        target: frag,
        props: props,
    })
    target.replaceWith(frag)
    return component
}
```

Comment: Thanks for crafting an asnwer !
May I ask why the `Object.assign()` is needed rather than just passing an object literal ?

Comment: I think this was just a piece of code I forgot to refactor. I edited the snippet.

Comment: Documentation about `createDocumentFragment` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

Comment: Do you have any idea if it's to to cast frag as an Element to satisfy Typescript ?
The component's constructor expects an Element | Document | ShadowRoot

Answer (score 2):

@azmeuk answer is truly amazing! I use the function albeit with a little addition. Instead of listing the attributes to return, I wrote a function to automatically get all the elements of an element.

```js
export function replaceTargetByComponent(target, Component, options) {
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const tagData = {
        //attributes
        attrs: get_attrs(target),
        //all other opts 
        ...options,
    };
    const component = new Component({
        target: frag,
        props: { tagData },
    });
    target.replaceWith(frag);
    return component;
}

// get all attributes of a given element
function get_attrs(el) {
    return el.getAttributeNames().reduce((acc, name) => {
        return { ...acc, [name]: el.getAttribute(name) };
    }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, I was creating HTML fallbacks separately and simply wanted to hydrate the whole dom with client-side Svelte components that exactly mirror the static html. However, using the method from [the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#Creating_a_component) was creating two nested `<html>` elements because it was appending to the target instead of replacing it.

Grabbing the "parent" of the element I want to replace seemed to work for me:

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

let target = document.querySelector('html').parentNode;

new App({
  target: target,
  hydrate: true
});
```

In my specific case that could more simply be written as:

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

new App({
  target: document,
  hydrate: true
});
```

Replacing the top level `<html>` element will give some console errors, but here are screenshots and more details for how we're implementing it in our project in case it's helpful: https://github.com/plentico/plenti/issues/65#issuecomment-696391302